# problem opening normal boot after TWRP install on nokia 3

Tags: twrp, nokia-3

by using sp flash tool i installed TWRP on nokia 3 phone and using fastboot loader i can open TWRP but i can not normal boot , when trying to boot normally only android logo appears.
Is it possible to open in normal boot.

Comment: Have you wiped any partitions(example like /system)? Please check whether it is the latest TWRP version for the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have install the custom recovery following reasons may cause problem-

1. Wrong version of twrp.
2. Wrong size of twrp recovery because some mediatek processors support 7mb of recovery.

So as you mentioned after installing twrp recovery device won't boot into system and it stuck on boot logo see the following guide to fix-

1. download stock rom of your device.
2. flash recovery.img from stock rom with sp flash tool as you flash twrp recovery.
3. This will return your device recovery mode to stock recovery form.
4. Now you can perform normal boot and your device won't stuck at logo.

Extra tips-

- try to find the right version of twrp recovery, unlock the bootloader and if won't find the twrp recovery for your device just build it yourself take help from Google hope it helps good luck.